# visual web developer C# issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

So I am getting an error after the page is live and the information is trying to post.

```
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("AddusConString");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql);

        int checkValue = 0;
        checkValue++; //increment ID used to build parameter name
        string parmName = String.Format("@Value{0}", checkValue);
        SqlParameter newParameter = new SqlParameter();
        newParameter.ParameterName = parmName;
            // Handle TextBox value
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FName", FName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LName", LName.Text);
```

It Highlights the

```
   SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("AddusConString");
```

Saying "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index0"

This is the code that I have for my web.config page

```
  <configuration>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="AddusConString" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=AddusWebsite;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/></assemblies></compilation>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 5):

You're using a string containing the value "AddusConString" rather than the value from the Web.Config. To get the value from the connection string section of the web.config you need to use the [ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134260.aspx) class.

Try:

```
string connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AddusConString"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
```

Comment: Now there is no error but when I click submit the page does not clear the data that was entered but it moves to the top of the page?!

Comment: Sounds like a completely different problem now. Have you debugged it to see what's going on?

Comment: Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?) I just got that now

Comment: Then at the top of your class you need to add a using reference. using System.Linq;

Comment: I do have this                                <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>

Comment: Good but you still to add using System.Linq; to the top of your class along with your other usings.

Comment: Do i need to add it to the Default.aspx page?

Comment: In the default.aspx.cs code-behind file (at the very top along with you other usings. ie) using System; using System.Linq;

Answer (score 2):

You have a few problems.

First, you must reference the connection string from web.Config through code similar to the following:

```
string myConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AddusConString"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString);
```

Second, there's nothing that associates the SqlCommand with the SqlConnection you've created, thusly:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
```

Lastly, and perhaps it was simply omitted for the purposes of the example, there's no code to indicate the query is ever going to be fired, such as:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //assuming the query is an Insert.
```

Comment: Good spot on the second... I assumed the third was just omitted for posting purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesnt recognise `"AddusConstring"` just like that.
Reference it so that it looks in the web.config:

```
string connString =  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AddusConstring"].ToString();
```